# Is it permissible to conduct research on homosexuality?

Tags: halal-haram, homosexuality

Is it permissible to conduct research on homosexuality, its cause and try to formulate a psychological cure for it?

Conducting research on homosexuality would indirectly means that we actually consider it a disease. And if we consider it to be a disease we are in other words questioning the judgement of Allah who punished the people Lut for their homosexual acts i.e. did Allah punish those who were in essence ill or having some sort of disease?

Words of the Quran about this and the action of Allah on them, seem to, establish a point that homosexuality is actually a voluntary and rebellious choice and which can't be considered as a disease.

Plus, based on the Islamic belief is it incumbent on a Muslim to consider the words of homosexuality apologists and who state that those sexual orientations are just natural and that's how nature made them, as blatant lies? And never agree with the [results](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/5483/4012) set forth by researchers that it is a natural disposition or influence taken from the surrounding?

*Answers should be well rounded and addressing all the questions.*

Comment: A lot of moot premises :conducting research does not necessarily  mean we consider it as disease, research can also be observational and many other types, and cures are even sought for "unhappy lives", "desperation", "envy","eroticism" , yet none of these are technically a disease.

Comment: About the Lut(puh) people, they were not only homosexuals, but also cruel people who attack nearby caravans and rape whoever they desire. When the 3 angels came to Lut(puh)'s house, they surrounded the house and wanted the angels for sex, but they never asked if the angels want it. They were going to rape them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Conducting research on homosexuality would indirectly means that we actually consider it a disease.

The logic of this statement is erroneous, the assumption that the *ultimate* logical consequence of inquiry (research) equals questioning the judgement of Allah is to impound a rule that criminalizes the inalienable right of thoughts. Islam unlike Christianity does not punish again "thought crimes."

Islam refers to the niyyah (intention) of a person when in relation to actions, the person can be doing a research case to be only trying to understand the nature of homosexuality, not to be "considering" it a disease. So the "indirectly" part is based on a assumption which can be disregarded, as it is based on ones niyyah, not thoughts.

> i.e. did Allah punish those who were in essence ill or having some sort of disease?

This brings up something interesting, how do you know the homosexuality of the past, is the homosexuality of today. There are cases known of when heterosexual people sleep with the same sex, yet still identify heterosexual, and live heterosexual lifestyles (i.e. marrying the opposite sex, scientists notice this, and some assume it to be just sexual release, as men mostly have the same libido levels).

> Words of the Quran about this and the action of Allah on them, seem to, establish a point that homosexuality is actually a voluntary and rebellious choice and which can't be considered as a disease.

The sentence above is speculation, while I give you that the Qur'an does seem to establish a point that the people of Lut did commit "homosexuality" voluntarily, and as a rebellious choice, there is no way to know if the homosexuality of the past referenced is the homosexuality of today classified by psychological associations. As well as with reference to the above answer/paragraph, where heterosexual people sleep with the same sex, yet still identify heterosexual, and live heterosexual lifestyles it could be to this that the Qur'an refers to.

> Plus, based on the Islamic belief is it incumbent on a Muslim to consider the words of homosexuality apologists and who state that those sexual orientations are just natural and that's how nature made them, as blatant lies? And never agree with the results set forth by researchers that it is a natural disposition or influence taken from the surrounding?

No, as I have reiterated many times in this answer, the Islamic belief does not make it incumbent one a Muslim to forbid the agreement by researchers that it is a natural disposition or influence taken from the surrounding. As the basis that the homosexuality described in the people of Lut story, is the same as homosexuality defined by today's society is a assumption, and a weak one at that.

> Is it permissible to conduct research on homosexuality, it's cause and try to formulate psychologically cure for it?

Socially I would assume many people would classify your actions as hate-related, however under Islamic sharia there is no issue to conduct research on homosexuality, and try to formulate psychologically cure for it.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree entirely with the answer that is quoting freud. Freud himself has proven his theories wrong (this is not our topic).

Homosexuality is not a disease, quoting from the other answer:

> All attempts to "treat" homosexuality have failed as conversion therapy
>   works only for those who are extremely religiously motivated and causes harm to those individuals. Abstinence works for both homosexuals and hetrosexuals who find conflict with their sexuality but autonomic functions eventually force the body to be somewhat sexual.

You are free to conduct any research on any topic you want if all you want is learning as islam have never put such limits:

> No shyness in science

But, be careful...

Treating homosexuality as a disease is a reason for all people to make sins and say that it is psychological disease.

I agree with the other answer in the page you linked, as it shows that islam and science are moving in parallel.

Comment: How does this satisfy the *well rounded* requirement?