# Is there reason to believe that homosexuality during the time of Prophet Lut is distinct from modern-day homosexuality?

Tags: homosexuality, prophet-lut

The following answer suggests the possibility that "homosexuality" during the time of Prophet Lut is distinct from modern-day "homosexuality".

> ... there is no way to know if the homosexuality of the past referenced is the homosexuality of today classified by psychological associations ...
>
> As the basis that the homosexuality described in the people of Lut story, is the same as homosexuality defined by today's society is [an] assumption, and a weak one at that.
>  <sub>[Opcode's answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11079/is-it-permissible-to-conduct-research-on-homosexuality/21733#21733) (score +3, accepted) to [Is it permissible to conduct research on homosexuality?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11079/is-it-permissible-to-conduct-research-on-homosexuality)</sub>

The evidence given to substantiate this claim is anecdotal and unreferenced (saying some heterosexual people engage in homosexual sex), and it's unclear (to me) how this evidence even connected to the claim.  Essentially, this question is a check of the above claim:

**Question**: Is there reason to believe that homosexuality during the time of Prophet Lut is distinct from modern-day homosexuality?

Answer (score 4):

Lut (AS) says:

> And Lot, when he said to his people, ‘What! Do you commit **a shameful sin** none in the world ever committed before you?! (7:80)

He is admonishing them for a shameful sin. Let us see what that sin is:

> Indeed you come to men with lust instead of women! Rather you are a profligate lot.’ (7:81)

So, the only description that he gives when he is describing their sin is 'coming to men with lust'.

So, maybe or maybe not the homosexuality of the people of Lut (AS) may have been different. The only description Quran gives of their sin is 'coming to men with lust', and if there was a different reason it was a sin (if it was only about their specific homosexuality), Allah would have described more specifically what they were being admonished for.

Comment: This response is not an answer. "Maybe or maybe not" is less informative, and more of a waste of reading time, than no response at all.

Comment: @CarlMasens I answered the claim referenced in the description and why it does not make a difference whether the type of homosexuality was different.

Answer (score 3):

### Notice:

I don't claim that what you are about to read is an absolute truth, for only Allah knows best, but it's represents what I know is true; You are free to accept it or reject it, but at least think about it.

#### Psychological associations do not justify a forbidden act

I'd like to know how `distinct` can it be???
Let's revise the Quran: 
`Surah An-Naml {54-55}`

> 54
>   وَلُوطًا إِذْ قَالَ لِقَوْمِهِ أَتَأْتُونَ الْفَاحِشَةَ وَأَنْتُمْ تُبْصِرُونَ 
>   And [mention] Lot, when he said to his people, "Do you commit immorality while you are seeing?
>
> 55
>   أَئِنَّكُمْ لَتَأْتُونَ الرِّجَالَ شَهْوَةً مِنْ دُونِ النِّسَاءِ ۚ بَلْ أَنْتُمْ قَوْمٌ تَجْهَلُونَ
>   Do you indeed approach men with desire instead of women? Rather, you are a people behaving ignorantly

This clearly mentions that the actions of people of Lut is the same as what homosexuals do today. The Act itself is considered an act of ignorance and strictly forbidden.

As for the "psychological associations" let me give this example:
Consider a mentally unstable person with a traumatic childhood, growing up to become a child rapist. He feels an uncontrollable urge to rape (for the sake of the example) every time he sees a **blonde** child. Does that make the act accepted or Halal in any way? **Never!**

In other words, the *psychological associations* do not determine what is considered Halal and what is considered Haram.

#### Understanding Homosexuality

Islam considers the existence of rape, pornography, adultery, homosexuality, child pornography, sex trafficking, and sexual harassment as signs of an unhealthy society. Islam set rules and boundaries to organize the sexual life of people to preserve a healthy society;

Of these rules we mention:

1. Ordering women to preserve their modesty and to cover
2. No sex before marriage
3. It is forbidden to approach your women from their behinds (anal)

Sex is like drugs, and sure acts like drugs in the brain (biologically): once you get used to a certain dose, you no longer enjoy it, and you seek a higher dose...
Even in the old days (100+ years ago), whether in Europe or anywhere in the world, people would dress modestly (mostly) which is why their societies did not suffer (as much as we do) from these unhealthy practices.

- The first dose of the drug called sex, was exposing women's bodies. That was the hype of the society for some time.
- Then society got used to women wearing short skirts and shorts, so increasing the dose up until sex before marriage is very common. Nowadays, very few (around the world) are those who remain virgin until marriage.
- Later regular sex became so common and boring, so uncommon acts started showing up like hardcore, BDSM, weird fetishes...
- The highly sexualized society got used to such practices and they are no longer fun or exciting so homosexuality started spreading.

These steps did not occur in a chronological order and some of these occurred simultaneously. It is not a discrete but rather a continuous process. Also, what may be satisfying to someone may not be to another, so the steps above are not general rules that apply to everyone.

#### Back to the verse: Psychology of the homosexual

According to explanations of the verses mentioned above, the people of lut were heterosexuals initially, and 40 years before they started doing homosexual acts, they started approaching their women from their behinds. Prophet Muhammad (Peace Be Upon him) called this act as *اللوطية الصغرى* or *the smaller homosexuality*. ("the smaller" meaning it leads to the full homosexuality).

40 years later, if they can do it to their women, they thought, why not do it with their men too?

I'm not saying that every homosexual nowadays have gone through all these steps above, but rather I'm presenting a study/analysis of *the society*, how homosexuality started spreading, and how it can be reduced in the society.

Notice how the 2 stories seem similar: homosexuals of lut started escalating their sexual practices to enhance their experiences, first by practicing the smaller homosexuality (anal with women) then to full homosexuality. 
While many, if not most, homosexuals nowadays are homosexuals by choice (after **losing** interest in heterosexual sex);
As for those who claim their homosexuality earlier in their lives, they are living in this highly-sexualized society we've been talking about, and their homosexual tendencies come from their childhood experiences (I know many homosexuals, and 100% of them were victims of sexual harassment as children by adults from the same sex).

As for the claim that homosexuality is biological, there are serious doubts about this and no one can prove this because science still does not have a 100% clear understanding of how sexuality works. 
(for example, science still cannot explain cases where a person having both X and Y chromosomes develops all the traits of a female; a healthy one)

Answer (score -3):

**No.**
The Homosexuality in the time of Prophet Lut (P.B.U.H.) is not different from modern-day homosexuality.